# Estoy empenzando en Unity y me desaparece un objeto

Tags: c++, unity

Estoy empezando en Unity para hacer un juego sencillo en 2D y si estoy haciendo que un personaje pase de un lugar a otro

```
collision.transform.position = target.transform.GetChild(0).transform.position;
```

Y me surge lo siguiente , si dentro del personaje le meto la Camara al hacer el salto va perfecto pero si la dejo fuera y la intento configurar al hacer el salto mi personaje desaparece. (Con dejarla fuera o dentro me refiero en la herencia,si metes dentro del pj la camara funciona si la dejas fuera desaparece en el salto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí el script de la cámara,

```
  void Awake()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    print(target.tag);
    print(target);
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x,tLX,bRX),
        Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y,bRY,tLY),
        transform.position.z
        );
}

public void SetBound (GameObject map)
{
    Tiled2Unity.TiledMap config = map.GetComponent<Tiled2Unity.TiledMap>();
    float cameraSize = Camera.main.orthographicSize;

    print(map);
    print(map.transform.position.x);
    print(map.transform.position.y);



    if (map.tag == "fondo" && map.transform.position.y==0 && map.transform.position.x==0)
    {
        tLX = 13 + cameraSize;
        tLY = 13- cameraSize;
        bRX = 13 + config.NumTilesWide - cameraSize;
        bRY = 13 - config.NumTilesHigh + cameraSize;
    }
    else if (map.tag == "casa") 
    {
        float auxBRX = 57.7f;
        float auxBRY = 41.9f;
        float auxTLY = 142.9f;

        tLX = (-12) + cameraSize;
        tLY = auxTLY - cameraSize;
        bRX = auxBRX + config.NumTilesWide - cameraSize;
        bRY = auxBRY - config.NumTilesHigh + cameraSize;
    }

    else
    {
        tLX = map.transform.position.x + cameraSize;
        tLY = map.transform.position.y - cameraSize;
        bRX = map.transform.position.x + config.NumTilesWide - cameraSize;
        bRY = map.transform.position.y - config.NumTilesHigh + cameraSize;
    }

}
```

y en el salto tengo lo siguiente para hacer la llamada de la camara

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<mainCamera>().SetBound(targetMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

parece que es un problema del movimiento del personaje, cuando la cámara se encuentra de Child del personaje, y mueves al personaje, en el salto te llevas la camara, esto significa que cuando haces el salto con la camara por fuera del player, probablemente se encuentre en una posicion donde no lo veas en la camara, para verificarlo corre el juego y ejecuta el salto, y en el inspector de unity revisa la posición nueva del player y si se encuentra dentro del enfoque de la camara despues de saltar.